# How to find last two digits of $2^{2016}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

What should the 'efficient' way of finding the last two digits of $2^{2016}$ be? The way I found them was by multiplying the powers of $2$ because $2016=1024+512+256+128+64+32$. I heard that one way would be with the **Chinese Remainder Lemma** but I don't really know how I should start?

Comment: As an alternative duplicate target also consider [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1385396/11619) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/679842/11619). The latter one has list of further essential duplicates as a comment. Observe the extra steps you need to do because the base $2$ shares a factor with $100$.

Comment: One answer to your question in lab's answer is that we can use the identity $$\ 4a\bmod 4n\, = 4(a\bmod n)\ $$ to pull out common factors using the *distributive law*. This decreases the modulus so simplifies computations. This might be clearer in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially we need $2^{2016}\pmod{100}$

As $(2^{2016},100)=4$

let us find $2^{2016-2}\pmod{100/4}$

Now as $2^{10}\equiv-1\pmod{25}$

$2^{2014}=2^{201\cdot10+4}=(2^{10})^{201}\cdot2^4\equiv(-1)^{201}\cdot2^4\equiv9\pmod{25}$

$$\implies2^2\cdot2^{2014}\equiv2^2\cdot9\pmod{2^2\cdot25}$$

Comment: Why did you find $2^{2014}$ and not $2^{2016}$? If I tried writing  $2^{2016}$ as $2^{201\cdot10+6}$ the final answer would be $2^2\cdot2^{2016}\equiv2^2\cdot11\pmod{2^2\cdot25}$ which is wrong. Can you please explain me why it doesn't work like this, too?

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu, I wanted to find $$2^n\equiv-1\text{or }1\pmod m$$ which is possible only if $(2,m)=1$

Answer (score 9):

**By brute force**:

Powers of $2$ end in

$$01,02,\color{blue}{04,08,16,32,64,28,56,12,24,48,96,92,84,68,36,72,44,88,76,52},04,08,16\cdots$$ and so on with a period of $20$.

Hence $$2^{2016}\to2^{16}\to36.$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[2]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}\left(\,{#2}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> This is an $\ds{\ul{old\ school}}$ proof:

1. Since $\ds{2^{2016} = \pars{2^{4}}^{2016/4} = 16^{504}}$, it's obvious the $\ds{\ul{2^{2016}\ last\ digit}}$ is $\ds{\color{#f00}{\large 6}}$.

   Namely, the last digit of  any $n^{\mathrm{th}}$-powers
   $\ds{\pars{n = 1,2,3,\ldots}}$ of $\ds{\ 16}$ is $\ds{\color{#f00}{6}}$.

   ---
2. Then, $\ds{{2^{2016} - 6 \over 10}= {16^{504} - 6 \over 10}}$ is an $\ds{\ul{integer}}$ and its last digit is the
   digit before the $\ds{2^{2016}}$ last digit:
   \begin{align}
   \fbox{$\ds{\ {16^{504} - 6 \over 10}\ }$} & = {\pars{16^{504} - 16} + 10 \over 10} = {16\pars{16^{503} - 1} \over 10} + 1 =
   {16\times 15 \over 10}\,{16^{503} - 1 \over 16 - 1} + 1
   \\[3mm] & =
   \fbox{$\ds{\ 24\sum_{n = 0}^{502}16^{n} + 1\ }$}\tag{1}
   \end{align}
   The above sum last digit is the last digit of
   $\ds{\pars{1 + 6\times 502} = 301\ul{3}.\ }$
   The last digit of $\ds{2\ul{4} \times 301\ul{3}}$ is $\ds{\ul{2}}$ such that the last digit of $\ds{\pars{1}}$ is
   $\ds{\pars{\ul{2} + \ul{1} = \color{#f00}{\large 3}}}$

   ---
3. Then,
   $\ds{2^{2016}\ \ul{last\ two\ digits}\ \mbox{is}\
   \color{#f00}{\large 36}}$.

Comment: Heh. +1 for steampunk and rabbits.

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for your remark. Sometimes it's nice to use 'brute force', 'old school', 'old tricks from the old trunk', etc... I like the other answers ( the 'mod' style is a quite useful tool ) but I feel we need some aditional feeling .

Answer (score 2):

You may combine an obvious fact:
$$ 2^{2016}\equiv 0\pmod{4} $$
with the less obvious fact that $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(25\mathbb{Z})^*$ to get:
$$ 2^{2016} \equiv 2^{2016\pmod{\varphi(25)}} \equiv 2^{16} \equiv (-1)\cdot 64 \equiv 11\pmod{25}$$
from which:
$$ 2^{2016}\equiv\color{red}{36}\pmod{100} $$
readily follows from the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: +1. Anyway: A professional mathematician sets the difference.

Comment: ... and some hasty user readily set a downvote :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio sir your proof is mind blowing!! I love group theory and I can't help but ask the last three digit of $2^{2017}$.

Comment: @MathCosmo: there is very little to adapt, since 2 is a generator mod 125, too.

Answer (score 1):

We need to find $2^{2016} \bmod 100$

We can calculate this fairly directly without the need for the Chinese Remainder Theorem to recombine the results from the different prime powers, although that is often a useful technique.

Although $2^2 \mid 100$, the values for exponents above $2$ will cycle as usual in accordance with Euler's Theorem, and the cycle length will divide $\lambda(100)=\text{lcm}(20,2)=20$, the reduced totient function (Carmichael function).

So since $2016 \equiv 16 \bmod 20 $ (and $16>2$),  $2^{2016}  \equiv 2^{16} \equiv (2^8)^2 \equiv 56^2 \equiv 6^2 \equiv 36 \bmod 100 $

Answer (score 1):

We use $ \ ca\bmod cn\,=\ c\ (a\bmod n),\, $ the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), $ $ to pull out $\,c=2^{\large 2}$
$\ \ \begin{align}
2^{\large 16+20I^{\phantom{|}}}\!\!\!\bmod 100\, &=\ 2^{\large 2}\,(\color{#c00}{2^{\large 14+20I}}\bmod{25})\\
&=\, 2^{\large 2}\,(\color{#c00}{3^{\large 2}}),  \ {\rm by}\  \bmod{25}\!:\,\ {\color{#c00}{2^{\large 14+20I}}}\!\equiv 2^{\large 14}\, \!\!\!\underbrace{(\color{#0a0}{2^{\large 20}})^{\large I}\! \equiv \color{#0a0}{\bf 1}^{\large I}}_{\rm\large\color{#0a0}{Euler}\ \phi(25)=20}\!\!\!\,2^{\large 14}\!\equiv (2^{\large  7})^{\large 2}\!\equiv\color{#c00}{ 3^{\large 2}}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

You can write

$$ 2^{2016} = 2^{32}  {(2^{32})}^2  {(2^{32})}^4  {(2^{32})}^8  {(2^{32})}^{16} {(2^{32})}^{32} $$

and

$$ 2^{32} = {({({(2^{4})}^{2})}^{2})}^{2}  $$

Calculating squares in $\text{ mod 100}$:

$\quad 16 \mapsto 56 \mapsto 36 \mapsto 96$

and so $2^{32} \equiv 96 \text{ mod 100}$ and since $96^{2} \equiv 16 \text{ mod 100}$ there is a cyclic pattern on these squares; using mental calculations and our cycle,

$\quad 2^{2016} \equiv (-4) (16) (56) (36)(-4)(16) \equiv$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad (16)(16)(56)(36)(16) \equiv$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad (56)(56)(36)(16) \equiv$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad (36)(36)(16) \equiv$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad (-4)(16) \equiv$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad 36 \text{ mod 100} $