# How to calculate last four digits of $2^{2017}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

can u suggest me any short trick of solving these kind of problems. How to find last four digits of any number raised to some power ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016

Comment: The standard approach is to use modular arithmetic, with the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and [Euler's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: Just to mention : TIFR GS 2018, conducted a few days ago, asked for the last three digits of this number. The answer was $072$, and the official (or rather, mine) solution says : note that $2^{n}$ and $2^{n+20}$ have the same last three digits after some time(for $n > 7$)! And therefore you find the last three digits of $2^{17}$. For four digits, you will have to proceed a little further.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2562678/44121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute this in terms of powers of $5$ and reduce modulo $5^4$ you can compute $$2^{2017}=2\cdot (1-5)^{1008}\equiv 2\cdot\left(1-5\binom{1008}1+25\binom {1008}2-125\binom {1008}3\right)\equiv$$and because of the factors $5^r$ you can reduce the binomials modulo $125, 25, 5$ respectively so $$\equiv2\cdot\left(1-5\cdot 8+25\cdot3-125\cdot 1\right)\equiv $$(which I did in my head using the indicated short cut) $$\equiv2\cdot-89\equiv 447$$

And $447$ leaves remainder $-1$ when divided by $16$ while $625$ leaves remainder $1$, so $447+625=1072$ will match residues modulo both $16$ and $125$.

Answer (score 8):

Since $10^4 = 2^4 \times 5^4$, my first reaction is one should use [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

For $2^4$, it is clear $2^{2017} \equiv 0 \pmod {2^4}$.

For $5^4$, we use following theorem

> For $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, we have $$a^{\varphi(b)} \equiv 1 \pmod b$$ where $\varphi(\cdot)$ is the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

For $a = 2$ and $b = 5^4$, we have $\varphi(5^4) = 4(5)^3 = 500$. This leads to
$$2^{2017} = 2^{4(500)+17} \equiv 2^{17} \equiv 65536\times 2 \equiv 1072\pmod {5^4}$$

It turns out we are lucky. Since $1072 \equiv 0\pmod {2^4}$ already, we don't need CRT to conclude $2^{2017} \equiv 1072 \pmod {10^4}$. 
As a result, the last $4$ digits of $2^{2017}$ is $1072$.

Comment: Another coincidence is that the answer uses same digits as the exponent 2017. +1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You want to find $2^{2017} \bmod 10000$. To do that, it suffices to find it $\bmod 16$ and $\bmod 625$. Finding it $\bmod 16$ is easy; to find it $\bmod 625$, use Euler's theorem that, if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then

$$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1\bmod n,$$

where $\varphi(n)$ is the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Can this reduce $2^{2017}$ into something more manageable?

Comment: We need $\pmod{10^4}$ right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes. I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like  [How to find last two digits of $2^{2016}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016),

I shall find $2^{2017-4}\pmod{10^4/2^4}$

As $2^2=5-1$

$\displaystyle2^{2012}=(5-1)^{1006}\equiv1-\binom{1006}15+\binom{1006}25^2-\binom{1006}35^3\pmod{5^4}$

Now $\displaystyle1006\equiv6\pmod{5^3}\implies\binom{1006}15\equiv5\cdot6\pmod{5^4}$

$\displaystyle\binom{1006}2\equiv15\pmod{5^2}\implies\binom{1006}25^2\equiv5^2\cdot15\pmod{5^4}$

and $\displaystyle\binom{1006}3\equiv0\pmod5\implies\binom{1006}35^3\equiv0\pmod{5^4}$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{2012+1}\equiv2(1-5\cdot6+5^2\cdot15)\equiv346\cdot2\pmod{5^4}$

Multiply out by $2^4$

Comment: A little more efficient than my binomial method I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular case of computing $a^k$ modulo $n$. Here $n=10000$.
The systematic method for doing this is "repeated squaring". As
$2^{2017}=2(2^{1013})^2$, first work out $2^{1013}$ modulo $10000$,
that is its last four digits. If these last four digits form the number
$a$ then $2^{2017}\equiv 2a^2\pmod{10000}$, so find the last four digits
of $2a^2$.

Of course to find the last four digits of $2^{1013}$ one proceeds recursively: $2^{1013}=2(2^{506})^2$, so find the last four digits of $2^{506}$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you want $2^{2017} $ mod $10000$.

Using the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $10000=2^45^4$, which is $5^34=500$,

we have $2^{2017}\equiv{2^{17}}=131072\equiv1072\bmod10000$.