# What is the 5th digit from the end of the number $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I thought of using $\text{mod } 10000$ on this but $10000$ and $5$ are not co-prime nor $10000$ is prime so I was not able to apply Fermat or Euler's Theorem . Any Hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please use parenthese?

Comment: Please re-write the question in MathJax, I am confused between $5^5^5^5^5$ and $((((5^5)^5)^5)^5)$

Comment: Did you mean mod $100000$?

Comment: You need Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner isn't it  $\pmod {10000}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016

Comment: @DerekLuna The question asks for the fifth last digit. mod 10000 gives the last four.

Comment: mod 100000 would be of no better either

Comment: @labbhattacharjee so $(5^5^5^5^5, 100000) = 5^5$, but it doesn't look obvious how to reduce the the power tower using your link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want $\bmod 100000$ to get the fifth digit from the end of the number.

$5^5\equiv1\bmod4$, so by Euler's theorem $5^{5^5}\equiv5\bmod8$,

so by Euler's theorem $5^{5^{5^{5}}}\equiv5^5\equiv5\bmod16$,

so by Euler's theorem $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}\equiv5^5=3125 \bmod32$.

Also,  $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}\equiv0\equiv3125\bmod5^5 $.

Therefore, since $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}\equiv3125\bmod 5^5$ and $\bmod2^5$,

by the Chinese remainder theorem $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}\equiv3125\bmod10^5$,

so the last five digits of $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}$ are $\color{blue}03125$.

Comment: I did not understand the 2nd step ,how did u use euler's theorem and wrote 5^5^5 congruent to 5 mod 8 ?

Comment: $\color{green]+}{5^5}\equiv\color{green}1\bmod4$, so $5^{\color{green}{5^5}}\equiv5^\color{green}1\bmod8$ because $\phi(8)=4$