# Euler's Theorem Discrete Mathematics Exponential Modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I m trying to solve the answer for this question using Eulers Theorem to calculate the exponential modulo.

```
3^2000 (mod 12).   Cannot apply Euler's theorem since gcd(3,12) is not equal to 1 .
```

Is there any way to convert this to another form where gcd() is equal to one and can apply  Euler's Theorem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783467/last-two-digits-of-141414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3^{2000}\equiv0\pmod 3$ and $3^2\equiv1\pmod4$,

so $3^{2000}\equiv9\pmod{12}$ by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Euler's theorem by noting a couple of things:

- You can still use it with the coprime part of the modulus as the gcd condition then holds.
- Euler totient is multiplicative on coprime parts, meaning you can  Still use the Euler totient of the original modulus ( though the resulting exponent is likely still big)
- If the exponent on the  base, is bigger than the exponents on the primes in their gcd, you can can say it's 0 mod that part of the modulus.
- If the exponent were really large ( say 78 digits plus if you want to wait that long) you could write in base one more than the Euler totient to decrease it.
- You can piece things together with Chinese remainder theorem.

In this case we have $3^{2000}\equiv 0\bmod 3$ and $3^{2000}\equiv 3^{0}\equiv 1\bmod 4$   which means by CRT that it's 9 mod 12.